# What is Triptych and how does it relate to Monero ring signatures?

Tags: cryptography, ring-signatures

Monero Research Lab recently published a research paper on Triptych: https://eprint.iacr.org/2020/018

What is Triptych, and what are its advantages and disadvantages compared to CLSAGs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Monero currently, we use a ring signature comprising of 10 decoy inputs to each input being spent - so a ring size of 11 - and it scales *linearly*. This last point is what prevents us from using a much larger anonymity set, as if we double our 11 to 22 for example, we double the size requirements for the signature(s) in the transaction. CLSAG offers a way to *compact* the size of the signature, however it to still scales linearly.

Now enter Triptych, devised by Sarang Noether and Brandon Goodell of the 
Monero Research Lab. This ring signature scheme scales *logarithmically* in size (and verification time). What this therefore offers Monero is a way to have larger anonymity sets (larger rings) without the linear cost in terms of size or verification time.

Simplified, larger anonymity sets offers better privacy but it has to be balanced against the size and verification time of the transactions. Thus, Triptych is a very interesting advancement for Monero - a way to increase the anonymity sets without impactful size and verification costs.

Comment: i think the verification time scales linearly still